# NSString variable is not NSstring

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsstring

I have a problem with NSString variable.

.h file

```
    NSString *strDeleteFilePath;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString* strDeleteFilePath;
```

.m File

```
    @synthesize strDeleteFilePath;
```

//After that when delete button click

```
    -(IBAction)deleteButton:(id)sender {
        UIButton *bt=(UIButton *)sender;
        strDeleteFilePath=[FunctionManager getDocumentDirectoryPath:@"MyPhotos"];
        strDeleteFilePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",strDeleteFilePath,[arrSaveImage objectAtIndex:bt.tag]];
        NSLog(@"strDeletePath=%@",strDeleteFilePath);

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Are you sure you want to delete this photo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
```

nslog prints proper path in string as below :

> strDeletePath=/Users/Samir/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/6.0/Applications/A72B7488-ABCB-48EC-91D0-CEE87FA121FE/Documents/MyPhotos/Dt20130411164806.png

when click on delete button in alert view...

```
   - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
       if (buttonIndex == 0){
           NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
           NSError *error = nil;
           if(![fileManager removeItemAtPath:strDeleteFilePath error:&error]) {
               NSLog(@"Delete failed:%@", error);
           } else {
               NSLog(@"image removed: %@", strDeleteFilePath);
           }
           [self setScrollviewItem];
       }
   }
```

it crash on line if(![fileManager removeItemAtPath:strDeleteFilePath error:&error])  and give following error ExE_BAD..ACCESS...

[image: error]
[image: ExE_Bad.....]

Thank You, in Advance.

Comment: strDeleteFilePath=[FunctionManager getDocumentDirectoryPath:@"MyPhotos"]; what FunctionManager does?

Comment: @Durgaprasad FunctionManager is mycustom class and it retrive path of given folder

Comment: Try this if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]). check if file exist @ that path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `self. strDeleteFilePath` instead of `strDeleteFilePath`.

Comment: This is right, with manual memory management you need to take advantage of the property memory semantics.  The current way of doing it simply makes an autoreleased string, so by the time the alert is done it is deallocated.  If you can't handle manual memory management, I encourage you to switch to ARC.

Comment: @borrrden I agree with you, Thank you for your valuable suggestion. I always remember.Thank you.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD By declaring the property, you wont need to declare the ivar anymore in your case in the .h file

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(IBAction)deleteButton:(id)sender {
    UIButton *bt=(UIButton *)sender;
    strDeleteFilePath=[FunctionManager getDocumentDirectoryPath:@"MyPhotos"];
    strDeleteFilePath=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",strDeleteFilePath,[arrSaveImage objectAtIndex:bt.tag]]; //change is here
    NSLog(@"strDeletePath=%@",strDeleteFilePath);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Are you sure you want to delete this photo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: This will work, but it is bad advice.  The current value of `strDeleteFilePath` will be leaked, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

replace this :

```
 if(![fileManager removeItemAtPath:strDeleteFilePath error:&error]) {
           NSLog(@"Delete failed:%@", error);
       } else {
           NSLog(@"image removed: %@", strDeleteFilePath);
       }
```

with:

```
if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: strDeleteFilePath])
{
   [fileManager removeItemAtPath: strDeleteFilePath error: nil];
}
else{
   NSLog(@"File not found");
}
```

Comment: Not only does this have nothing to do with the question, but this question already had an accepted answer for 30 minutes before you answered.  -1

Comment: This has everything to do with the question, because before removing the file it is a good practice to check whether that file exists in the document directory or not :-|

Comment: It may or may not be good practice, but that is irrelevant.  The issue here is something else altogether.  The question was why does that NSString variable cause a bad access error.  The code above will not fix that error.

Comment: I use ARC, so I have never faced this problem. And if you feel your answer is relevant to the above question then, please clear my doubt, what is the funda behind , using self.strDeleteFilePath instead of strDeleteFilePath. Not only me, everybody will be benefited by your answer. .:-)

Comment: with example. don't comment, only answer.

Comment: You can see a summary of the difference in mani's answer.  It would be overkill to put an entire memory management primer into an answer on SO.  That's what Apple's memory management documentation is for.  The key is the difference between retain and assign.

Comment: I am not asking you the difference between retain and assign. I am asking you why self.str instead of str?

Comment: can you tell me, self.str doesn't increase the retain count or it just assigns the value without copying / retaining

Comment: Because self.str causes a retain (it is declared as a retain property), and str causes an assign (no call to retain on an autoreleased object)

Comment: are you sure?  how can str assign when it is declared as retain?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  I was programming for iOS before ARC came around.  Look at the property definition:  @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString* strDeleteFilePath;.  That means that `self.strDeleteFilePath` will retain its object.  The underlying variable `strDeleteFilePath`, however, is just a simple pointer and will not retain.  In manual memory management, you have to do the retaining yourself by sending a `retain` message to it.  `strong` pointers do not exist.  Everything is `unsafe_unretained` under manual memory management.

Comment: thanks a lot. now i got satisfactory answer. :-) . But one thing i didnt understand, actually I've some doubt regarding unsafe_unretained, Why everything is unsafe_unretained under manual memory management?

Comment: Because the concepts of `strong` and `weak` are ARC-only.